# Need alternative of GridFsTemplate.store() in dynamodb

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa, amazon-dynamodb

We are shifting our code from mongo to dynamodb.

There GridFsTemplate is being used, how can i replace in dynamodb with spring data.

GridFSFile store(InputStream content, String filename, String contentType, DBObject metadata)

Above store method is to be replaed with dynamo-springdata stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, DynamoDB doesn't have the exact equivalent of GridFS. In DynamoDB, you can store the large files in S3 bucket and save the reference of the S3 bucket in the DynamoDB table.

I am not sure whether the Spring Data DynamoDB version (i.e. as it is a community version) that you are using has features to refer to S3 bucket link. However, the AWS SDK class **DynamoDBMapper** has methods to perform this.

Please refer the below links.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/dynamodbv2/datamodeling/DynamoDBMapper.html

[Example of creating the S3 link](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/dynamodbv2/datamodeling/S3Link.html)

Answer (score 0):

You should look at using Spring Data DynamoDB with [Spring Content](https://paulcwarren.github.io/spring-content/) S3.

Spring Content provides an abstraction allowing you to associate content with Spring Data entities.  The S3 module for Spring Content allows you to store that content in S3.